# How to filter in a Powershell Pipe using a blocklist in a extern file like a .txt

Tags: powershell

I need a Powershellscript that reads all installed Programs, filters them and puts them in a .txt File.
I got the basic function but I would like to enhance the script by Filtering out certain Programs using a blocklist. My First try down below works with Variables I have to declare in the script and I dont like that really. The Variables block some Entries with the same start but I want to block more Entries with Random names, I want to use a seperate .txt File as a block list.
I allready read to use Get-Content to import the Strings from the File where I get a Array Variable I believe but from there on I dont know ho to proceed, everthing I tried didnt work.

Thats from my Blocklist:

> Microsoft Visual C++
> Microsoft .NET
> vs_
> Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime
> NVIDIA
> Microsoft ASP.NET
> Toolkit Documentation
> Microsoft TestPlatform SDK Local Feed
> Windows System Image Manager on amd64
> Windows PE x86 x64 wims
> Windows PE x86 x64
> Windows Deployment Tools
> Windows Deployment Customizations
> Kits Configuration Installer
> User State Migration Tool
> VS Immersive Activate Helper
> Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 3.1
> Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0 Refresh

Thats the Code I got so far:

```
$ignore1="Microsoft Visual C++"; $ignore2="Microsoft .NET"; $ignore3="vs_"; $ignore4="Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime"; $ignore5="NVIDIA"; $ignore6="Microsoft ASP.NET"
$Outputfile="C:\...\temp\test.txt"
$Filterfile="C:\...\Skripts\Funktionen\blocklist.txt"

$List64 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*    | Select-Object DisplayName, Publisher, DisplayVersion, InstallDate 
$List32 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*                | Select-Object DisplayName, Publisher, DisplayVersion, InstallDate
$List = $List64 + $List32
$filters = Get-Content $filterFile

$List | Where-Object DisplayName | 
    Where-Object {($_.DisplayName -notlike "$ignore1*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "$ignore2*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "$ignore3*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "$ignore4*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "$ignore5*") -and ($_.DisplayName -notlike "$ignore6*")} |
     Where-Object DisplayName | Sort-Object -Property Publisher | Format-Table > $Outputfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PowerShell 7.2, there is *no* direct way to match a string against an *array* of patterns - neither with `-match` (regexes) nor with [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) (wildcard expressions).

- There's a green-lighted - but not implemented - proposal to introduce such support for `-like` (and its negated form, `-notlike`) - see [GitHub proposal #2132](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2132)
- Two *asides*:

  - If you're searching through *strings*, the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet *does* support multiple regex-pattern / literal-substring arguments.
  - Matching *entire, literal strings* against arrays *is* already supported, via the [`-in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) or its operands-reversed variant, [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains).

**For now, your best bet is to construct a *single* [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) that is the equivalent of your multiple `-like` operations**, and to use that with the `-notmatch`, the negated form of `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match):

```
# Define the list (array) of display-name substrings to ignore.
# This list could also come from a file, via Get-Content:
#   $ignoreList = Get-Content $filterFile
$ignoreList = "Microsoft Visual C++", "Microsoft .NET", "vs_", "Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime", "NVIDIA", "Microsoft ASP.NET"

# Construct a single regex with alternation (|) from it, escaping
# each string so that is treated literally during regex matching.
# The regex is anchored with ^ to ensure that the strings match at the 
# start of the display names. Given that -match matches *substrings* by
# default, additional characters, if any, may follow in the display name.
# In short: ... -match '^foo' is the equivalent of ... -like 'foo*'
$reIgnore = '^(' + ($ignoreList.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|') + ')'

# ...

# Now you can filter the display names
# against the regex with the -notmatch operator:
$List | Where-Object DisplayName | Where-Object DisplayName -notmatch $reIgnore |
  Sort-Object -Property Publisher > $Outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @mklement0 it works now. I have a File somewhere to define the filters, in this case Programs I dont need in the List at the end.

```
$Outputfile="C:\__Somewhere__\temp\test.txt"
$filters = Get-Content "C:\__Somewhere__\filterfile.txt"

$filter = '^(' + ($filters.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|') + ')'

$List64 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*    | Select-Object DisplayName, Publisher, DisplayVersion, InstallDate 
$List32 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*                | Select-Object DisplayName, Publisher, DisplayVersion, InstallDate
$List = $List64 + $List32

$List | Where-Object DisplayName | Where-Object DisplayName -notmatch $filter | Sort-Object -Property Publisher > $Outputfile
```